# Remove console.log wrapper that Jest adds in tests

Tags: jestjs

```
  console.log src/index.js:23
    [@langurama/log] Validating user configuration.
```

I would like to remove the `console.log src/index.js:23` which Jest adds in tests. Are there any configuration values to set this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Origin line it was called ta!